# c# SerialPort Write large byte array

Tags: c#, serial-port

I have a C# application that open a SerialPort to a modem and sends some AT commands.
At some point I send an ATDT command to call a telephone number.
After doing that I have to send some large data containing an audio of some synthetized text.

The problem is that when I pick up the phone I can hear only part of the message, the voice seems truncated at some point, I can hear only part of the message.
Sometimes the ATDT command returns OK even before the modem started composing the number, resulting in making a mute call.

From the modem manual I see that I have to use the following parameters: 115200, No parity, 1 stop bit, flow control XonXoff.
I use DtrEnabled = true, RtsEnabled = false

The command sequence I'm sending is:

- ATZ
- AT+FCLASS=8
- AT+VSM=130,8000
- ATDT
- AT+FLO=1 // XonXoff
- AT+VTX
- com.BaseStream.Write(voiceBuffer, 0, voiceBuffer.Length);
- SendTerminator // 0x10 0x03
- ATH
- ATZ

voiceBuffer is usually 150K

Comment: Do not enable XonXoff handshaking for binary data.  Such data is going to contain an Xoff character.  Only RTS/CTS handshaking is ever appropriate, that only matters for the handshaking between the modem and the app.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I just tried but the problem remains. Now the voice is truncated in a different point, and I can hear the end. To be exact the text I send is "Test to check if you can hear me" and I can hear "Test to ....... hear me"

Comment: I used Handshake.RequestToSend, DtrEnabled = true, RtsEnabled = true, AT+FLO=2

Comment: Hard to guess what AT+FLO actually means, it isn't standard.  Document your question better and mention the actual modem you use.  Review the [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voice_modem_command_set) and note the trouble it documents, particularly with Conexant chipsets.

Comment: From the modem manual AT+FLO allows to set Flow Control. 0 = none, 1 = use XonXoff, 2 = Use RTS/CTS. Modem is a GenPac 92c

Comment: By the way, subscribing to the ErrorReceived event I notice that I get several Frame errors while writing the voice data.